# Javascript DropDown menu with ajax and json

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

this is my code in HTML

---

```
<!-- Javascript DropDown menu -->
<label>Select le groupe</label>
<select id="groupe" onchange="yyyyy";>
<option value="">Select le groupe</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

i want to use dropdown in my code. in my code javascript i have a function

```
function getTable() {
      $.ajax({
              dataType: 'json',         
              type: 'GET',
              url: 'call/json/mytables',
              xhrFields: {
                         withCredentials: true
                },
              success: function(response) {
                  console.log(response); 
                  sendQuery(response[0]);
              },
          });
    }
```

like this and also function(response) give me Json that i need for my DropDown in onchange="yyyyy", 
but i don't know how i can use it ????????

Comment: Don't understand what you have and what you need, try to explain more

Comment: You can simply do it using .append() of jQuery. Just prepare your all option tag in a string in success method and append it to your select tag.

Comment: if response is an array, just loop through it creating options, and append it to the select

Comment: @FSou1 i want to send the data to my DropDown.

Comment: Ok, what data do you want to send and how do you want to process this data by DropDown?

Comment: sorry i am Beginner, i don't know we can say response is an array but it work like an array.

Comment: @ FSou1 you know i have different table and different user and every user can be connected with some table, in my code when on user connected in the site, the function(response) send us that our user access to which table and i want to show this in my DropDown, like this when my user connected with the site he can  to choose that he want to connected with wich table....

Comment: the drop down is already populated right? then use `$("#dropdownid").val(response[0]) or $("#dropdownid").text(response[0])` to select the option, IF that is what you wanted to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to request the data for your dropdown from the server (your code is already doing that) and then parse the response based on what format your server is returning. If we assume it's in JSON format then you can use `JSON.parse(response)` in your response callback, otherwise you will have to write some custom parsing code. *If that's the case please leave a comment with the relevant info about your response format.*

To fill the dropdown you can use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over your data array and append `<option>` elements to your `<select>` element.

Here is a [working jsFiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/2BN8X/3/) and below is the updated code

```
// disable the select control until you get the data
$("#groupe").prop('disabled', true);    

function populateSelectWithOptions($select, data)
{
    // remove any exisiting contents
    $select.html('');

    //iterate over the data and append a select option for each item
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $select.append('<option value="' + val.tableId + '">' + val.tableName + '</option>');
    });

    // enable the select control
    $select.prop('disabled', false);
}

function getTable() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'call/json/mytables',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function(response, status) {
            console.log(response, status);
            if (status == "success")
            {
                // we expect a response in a JSON format
                response = JSON.parse(response);

                // if the response is not in the json format then you will have to
                // write some custom parsing code here

                populateSelectWithOptions($("#groupe"), response);
            }
        },
    });
}

// request the data
getTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

In below code,`data[i].x` and `data[i].y`(is just an example).It will vary and depend on your json data.Just a sample regarding how to go about things. Place this code in your success part.

```
            var data=JSON.parse(response);//to parse the json_encoded data

            for(var  i=0;i< data.length;i++)
            {
                alldata += "<option id='"+data[i].x+"'>"+data[i].y+"</option>";
            }

            document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = alldata;//for javascript
or
            $("#id").html(alldata);//for jquery
```

Comment: could you explain for me here ?                http://jsfiddle.net/armon000/gRRaZ/

Comment: @user225049:the thing is i need some php for getting the response.Since there is no response ,i cant demonstrate how to do it,but I can answer your questions if you have any doubts...

Comment: @user225049: feel free to check the other fiddle that shows a possible solution here http://jsfiddle.net/2BN8X/3/. Others feel free to fork that if you think it could be improved. It will save you some time since the request/response is already set up.

Comment: @Ma3x:great...you just gave him the guidance he needed..+1 for comment,if possible just simplify it for him...

Comment: @MESSIAH: I hope it helps him. What do you think could be simplified? The comment? Or the code? Which part?

Comment: @Ma3x:the code inside fiddle!!!never the less..i think its worth the pain for user if he learns it himself..

Comment: @MESSIAH: Hmm. I tried to comment on everything I added/changed and I used his own code as base. I really don't know how to explain it in a more simple way :) Maybe you mean a classic loop instead of `$.each`? But anyway, if you see any part that could be simplified feel free to change it and post the updated link.