# Dropdown menu in HTML\PHP using MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web

I want to list a dropdown menu in my HTML form, that the user can select the item they want, using a dropdown menu (based on items in database)
I have researched a lot, and come to this as last resort!
Please explain, and help.

it should look like:
  Select a Product:
          -dropdown menu-
  Quantity: 86

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BuyingTransaction</title>
    </head>
<body>
<form action= "BuyingTransaction.php" method="post">
<select class="form-dropdown" style="width:150px" id="input_5" 
name="ProductNames">
</form>

<?php

    $username="22243339";
    $password="X23CZw2X";
    $server="localhost";
    $database="DB_22243339";


    $sqlConnect = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);

    // Check connection to the database
    if(!sqlConnect)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqlerror());
    }

    mysqli_select_db($sqlConnect, $database);


    $filter = mysql_query("SELECT ProductName FROM Products", $sqlConnect);
    menu = "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter))
    {
        $menu .="<option>" . $row['dropdown_option'] . "</option>";
    }
    // Close menu form
    $menu = "</select></form>";
    echo $menu;;
    mysqli_close(sqlConnect);
?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mysql_* extension is long dead

Comment: use one method like mysql,mysqli or pdo. so you don't have any problem in future

Answer (score 0):

You function is incorrect, it should be:

```
mysqli_query($sqlConnect,"SELECT ProductName FROM Products");
```

and don't forget `mysqli_connect` &`mysqli_fetch_array` mysql_* extension is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BuyingTransaction</title>
    </head>
<body>
<form action= "BuyingTransaction.php" method="post">  
<?php

    $username="22243339";
    $password="X23CZw2X";
    $server="localhost";
    $database="DB_22243339";


    $sqlConnect = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password,$database) or die("Error");

    // Check connection to the database
    if(!sqlConnect)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ');
    }

    $filter = mysqli_query($sqlConnect,"SELECT ProductName FROM Products");
    menu = " <select class='form-dropdown' style='width:150px' id='input_5' 
name='ProductNames'>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($filter))
    {
        $menu .="<option>" . $row['dropdown_option'] . "</option>";
    }
    // Close menu form
    $menu = "</select></form>";
    echo $menu;;
    mysqli_close(sqlConnect);
?>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you set result mode to  `$sqlConnect`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function in PHP.
2. Return a response in JSON format.
3. Do the ajax call to the function.
4. Use jquery or any other javascript function to generate it.

[Javascript DropDown menu with ajax and json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877395/javascript-dropdown-menu-with-ajax-and-json)